# Modal Angular 2 body

Tags: model, typescript, angular

I'm trying to put variables like this '{{variable}}' inside of the body of a bootstrap modal but it doesn't work.
I'm doing this in Angular2. 
This is my HTML:

```
<div> <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="modal.alert()
    .title('Model')
    .body('testing model angular 2' {{variable}})
    .okBtn('ok')
    .open();">Open Model</button> </div>
```

and this is my class:

```
export class App {
    constructor(private modal: Modal, private elementRef: ElementRef,
                private injector: Injector, private _renderer: Renderer) {}
}
```

The modal is working fine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smzCE.jpg)

The problem is: I need to present a Database table with some variables in an HTML table, and I don't know to do it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not supposed to work. `{{}}` only works in the template of a component directly, not in HTML passed as string.

Use instead:

```
<div> <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="modal.alert()
    .title('Model')
    .body('testing model angular 2' + variable)
    .okBtn('ok')
    .open();">Open Model</button> </div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to style a div inside the "  body(' <div id='style' > </div> ')  " ?